# Control flow task in SSIS stops after first one

Tags: sql, ssis

I've looked around yet can't seem to find a solution for my problem. I have a control flow in SSIS to import files. (Looks like new members can't post images so you can find the link [here](http://i.imgur.com/Ohz5XLf.png). The pattern repeats for several files.) The script task checks if the file exists and uses an expression and constraint success condition to choose what to do next.

If file 1 exists, it import to a location (as intended), then stops the entire process when that specific block completes (not as intended). It doesn't check if file 2 exists. I can't figure out what is stopping it. Do I need to add a constraint to the arrow after the import file block, or is there a setting in the executed package task itself that I need to change to tell it to return to the "higher level" package to continue with the next file exists check?

Comment: Not sure why your solution doesn't work, but another way to do this would be to put both "File 1" steps in a sequence container, and same for the two "File 2" steps, and have a precedence constraint going from the File1 container to the File2 container.

Comment: Not sure if that would work, I still need all the file exists checks to run regardless of which files do or don't exist.

Comment: Try setting the ForcedExecutionResult property on "Import File 1" to success and see if it still hangs

Comment: Also what is the expression that you have set on the link between "check if file 1 exists" and "check if file 2 exists".

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj - no problem, just use On Completion instead of On Success for the precedence constraint between the two containers.  Or have the File Exists check return success to the container if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @SFrejofsky - The script task checks if the file exists, and if it doesn't, sets a FileExists variable to 0. The link uses an expression and constraint success condition of @FileExists==0. How will ForceExecutionResult affect checking for existing file?

Comment: @TabAlleman - I tried that and it still stops at the same place.

Comment: Can you put up a screen shot of the control flow you tried following my suggestion, and another of the details of the precedence constraint between the two containers?

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj If the File exists then you boolean is going to be a 1 and then the expression will not return true on the link between check file 1 and check file 2 even if the import package task finishes you are not satisfying all of the constraints and expressions tied to check file 2. That is why the package stop at this point each time. And if the file does not exist your package will stop as well because you will not get a returned success from the execute package task. if you were to change this to a completion it still wouldn't work because there is nothing to return if it doesn't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. As SFrejofsky mentioned, having two conditional statements leading to the next "check if file exists" block is what was disallowing the package to continue.

The package runs as intended after I made two changes:

- Switching the precedence constraint to Completion between importing file 1 and checking file 2, so the link will always work as long as the import finishes.
- Setting the constraint to Logical OR. Only one of the links, rather than two, needs to run for the package to continue onto checking file 2. I believe this was the main problem, as the package was set up in a way that only one link could run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to assume that you are choking the process with the constraints and expressions you placed on the links from task to task. If you have two links leading into 1 task all of the constraints and expressions must be met to execute that next task.

Being that you have conditional logic in place whether or not the file exist leads me to believe that this is your problem.

Take the conditional logic off of the links between the packages and handle the flow of the package in the child package. Pass the child package a variable that indicates whether or not the file exists. your first step in the child package should be to validate that information and act accordingly.

That way the link between check if file 1 exist and check if file 2 exists will always be in a ready state and then check if file 2 exists will only fire if the file import for file 1 is successful.

I can not speak for what you import process is doing but I would suggest putting a logging feature in so that you can force the child package to return success and log any errors that may have occurred with that file. this will allow the process to continue to flow even if there are issues with one of the many files you are trying to import.